# ¿Como recorrer una lista simplemente enlazada?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy creado una app de pregutas, para lo cual he usado una lista simplemente enlazada cuando se presione un boton quiero que se muetre los objetos que contiene la lista siembargo cuando presiono el boton no muestra nada he revisado el metodo BuscarPosicion pero considero que esta bien, ¿no se que estoy haciendo mal? o ¿cual deberia ser la forma correcta de recorrer la lista para que cada vez que presione un boton se muestre en orden los objetos que tiene la lista?.

cualquier sugerencia o aporte me serie de gran ayuda.

adjunto codigo que uso:

Clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo {
    private Preguntas Informacion;
    private Nodo referencia;

    public Nodo(Preguntas informacion) {
        Informacion = informacion;
    }

    public Preguntas getInformacion() {
        return Informacion;
    }

    public void setInformacion(Preguntas informacion) {
        Informacion = informacion;
    }

    public Nodo getReferencia() {
        return referencia;
    }

    public void setReferencia(Nodo referencia) {
        this.referencia = referencia;
    }
}
```

Clase Preguntas

```
public class Preguntas {
    private String pregunta;

    public Preguntas(String pregunta) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
    }

    public String getPregunta() {
        return pregunta;
    }

    public void setPregunta(String pregunta) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
    }
```

Clase ListaSimple

```
public class ListaSimple {
    private Nodo primero; //Acceder al primer nodo de la lista
    private int size;

    //Constructor
    public ListaSimple() {
        this.primero = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    //Método para saber si la lista esta vacía
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.primero == null;
    }
   //Métodos para agregar Nodos a la lista
    //Agregar al inicio
    public void addBegin(Preguntas valor) {
        Nodo nodo = new Nodo(valor);
        //nodo.setInformacion(valor);
        if(isEmpty()) {
            this.primero = nodo;
        }else {
            nodo.setReferencia(primero);
            this.primero = nodo;
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    //Agregar al final
    public void addEnd(Preguntas valor) {
        Nodo nodo = new Nodo(valor);
        //nodo.setInformacion(valor);
        nodo.setReferencia(null);
        if(isEmpty()) {
            this.primero = nodo;
        }else {
            Nodo aux = this.primero;
            while(aux.getReferencia() != null) {
                aux = aux.getReferencia();
            }
            aux.setReferencia(nodo);
        }
        this.size++;
    }
 public String buscarPosicion(int p) throws Exception {
        if((p >= 0) && (p < this.size)) {
            if(p == 0) {
                return this.primero.getInformacion().getPregunta();
            }else {
                Nodo aux = this.primero; //Nodo de acceso a la lista
                for(int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
                    aux = aux.getReferencia();
                }
                return aux.getReferencia().getInformacion().getPregunta();
            }
        }else {
            throw new Exception("La posición esta fuera de la lista.");
        }
    }
```

Clase MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ListaSimple listaSimple = new ListaSimple();
  Nodo nodo;

   private Button btn;
   private TextView txt;
   private int con = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listaSimple.addBegin(new Preguntas("hola"));
        listaSimple.addEnd(new Preguntas("como"));
        listaSimple.addEnd(new Preguntas("tas"));

        Log.i("log-1",listaSimple.getSize() +"");


        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);

 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         try {
             txt.setText(listaSimple.buscarPosicion(con));
             con++;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 });


    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Nicolás, para tenerlo claro ¿lo que te estaría fallando es la parte de              txt.setText(listaSimple.buscarPosicion(con));, verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tenes un problema al buscar posición. Vos estás haciendo esto:

```
public String buscarPosicion(int p) throws Exception {
    if ((p >= 0) && (p < this.size)) {
        if (p == 0) {
            return this.primero.getInformacion().getPregunta();
        } else {
            Nodo aux = this.primero; // Nodo de acceso a la lista
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
                aux = aux.getReferencia();
            }
            return aux.getReferencia().getInformacion().getPregunta();
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("La posición esta fuera de la lista.");
    }
}
```

El problema de esto es que solo va a funcionar cuando quieras buscar el primer elemento de la lista. Al buscar otros, vas a tener un NullPointer por falta de referencia. Ejemplo:

Imaginate que tenes dos elementos en tu lista, y vos querés acceder al último (vos mandarías a buscarPosición el valor 1, ya que 0 sería el primero). Con el código actual, acá te fallaría:

```
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
      aux = aux.getReferencia();
}
return aux.getReferencia().getInformacion().getPregunta();
```

Porque al i ser menor que p, va a entrar, va acceder a ese segundo item pero después en el return va a intentar acceder a la referencia de ese segundo item (la cual no existe, porque no hay un tercer item). Debería ser algo así:

```
    public String buscarPosicion(int p) throws Exception {
    if ((p >= 0) && (p < this.size)) {
        if (p == 0) {
            return this.primero.getInformacion().getPregunta();
        } else {
            Nodo aux = this.primero; // Nodo de acceso a la lista
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
                aux = aux.getReferencia();
            }
            return aux.getInformacion().getPregunta();
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("La posición esta fuera de la lista.");
    }
}
```